# Formal term to web-ify a piece of existing software or program or a module?

Tags: web-development, development-process, terminology

There is a software we run as a windows service. Its currently not designed to take a huge load. So we kind of need this service to be hosted over http so that multiple clients can make use of it. Its not the whole windows service as such, but some modules it uses. Those modules are currenly not designed to work as "web service" (generic sense).

What would be the formal word for this?

Comment: Why should there be a formal word for this?

Comment: @JanHudec so that our tounge wouldn't slip saying "expose as web service" repeatedly...

Comment: @deostroll: That explains why you want it. But I asked why it should exist. Do you think it's so common or so special to have a common name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"[Webify](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=webify)" is the closest you're likely to get**

After [consulting English StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/87949/1995) the consensus appears to be that an "-ify" suffix is perfectly acceptable in everyday English. Consequently, when you get into conversations with other web developers working on the project they will be more likely to understand you when you use the technojargon.

Answer (score 1):

I've most commonly heard the term "modernization" used to describe this process, but have also heard it called "web migration" and "web-enabling." Here's a quick [definition of modernization from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_modernization), and while it's not a perfect match, it seems pretty close to what you're looking for.